# CSAPP: variable-size arrays VS Fixed-size arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am studying CMU 15-213 which discusses about computer organizations & structures. Currently I went through the part discussing about arrays. 
The following example shows the difference between Fixed-size array and variable-size array: [image: 1. fixed sized array code]
[image: 2. variable sized array code]

the first example, fixed-sized array, the column number C=16, size of element K=4, so C*k=64, and the code use salq to get 64*i; the second example, variable-sized array, the column number C is a variable so we don't know it until compile time; thus we have to use imulq rather than salq. In this context, variable-sized array is more expensive. However, I think this is due to C*k = 64, if we set C to 15 or 17, then C*k = 60 or 68, and then we might not use only one salq operation. So generally speaking, if the fixed-size array's C*k does not equal to 2^n, then the two ways of setting up arrays are equally computational expensive?

Comment: And why can't you do the experiment yourself?

Comment: What about the expense of passing the size around?

Comment: FTW, for a static fixed-size matrix C=17, K=7 icc in `-O3` mode generates code as though it was a contiguous array of size 136, i.e. it swaps the meaning of C and K internally and rounds up K to 8, resulting in a `shlq $3, %rax` for `fix_ele`.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of micro optimizations you shouldn't concern yourself about. Instead, strive to write readable programs. For example, question the use of `fix_matrix`. It is very bad practice to hide pointers behind typedefs, because it confuses the reader and makes the program far less readable/maintainable. I'd spend my energy on such issues, rather than counting CPU instruction cycles.